# angular adding "unsafe" to a "mailto" link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following line of code that I have used a million times:

```
<a href="mailto:{{email}}" ng-hide="cancel">Contact</a>
```

Angular adds an `unsafe:` in front of the link.

I obviously know that Angular is supposed to do that but the documentation says that it should let through html and mailto.

I tried nonetheless to add a `$compileProvider` to no avail:

```
.config( [
'$compileProvider',
function( $compileProvider )
  {   
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);
  }
])
```

Comment: Interesting. I had the same issue and that answer worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491931/use-compileprovider-to-avoid-unsafe-links