# Use $compileProvider to avoid unsafe links

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have no trouble injecting things like $scope and $location and $routeProvider, why is $compileProvider different?

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15637622/1272965), I understand that I have to instruct angular to not prefix certain links (sms in my case), but I can't apply the answer in my project.  It says I should add this:

```
angular.module('myModule', [], function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file):/);
});
```

But the chrome console says:

> "angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   $compileProviderProvider <- $compileProvider"

That "provider-provider" thing made me think that the real name of the service is just $compile (and that angular is tacking on the "provider" suffix:

```
angular.module('myModule', [], function ($compile) {
    $compile.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file):/);
});
```

But then, predictably, I guess, I get:

> angular.js:13550 TypeError: $compile.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist is not a function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you have to add it as a config:

```js
angular.module('myModule').config(['$compileProvider',
  function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file):/);
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck.  I get  "angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mytodoApp due to:
TypeError: $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist is not a function"  (the only thing I changed in your suggestion was myModule to mytodoApp (which is my app name).

Comment: did you try "aHrefSanitizationWhitelist" ? Because the urlSanitizationWhiteList Method got removed and splitted to imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist and aHrefSanitizationWhitelist

Comment: Thanks.  That did the trick.  My real problem was the syntax chaining the config around my other configs.

Comment: 3rd `module` argument is `config` function, so separate `config` is not necessary.